# Calendar, Is there a different UIID for days outside the selected month?

Tags: codenameone

I would like to apply a different style for day before 1 and after last day of the month.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5xfD.png) of what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the disabled style of the same UIID.

My original answer was inaccurate here it is below:

The current implementation of setting the day text looks like this:

```
protected void updateButtonDayDate(Button dayButton, int currentMonth, int day) {
    dayButton.setText("" + day);
}
```

You can just override one of the updateButtonDayDate methods and set the UIID accordingly.

Comment: I try it, but `updateButtonDayDate` is only call for days of month, not for days before and after. And Buttons is not enabled, so I can't manage event.

Comment: My original answer was wrong, I fixed it. As far as I can tell it is called with all days and not just the current calendar day. It seems you are getting confused because of the disabled state.

Comment: Thanks. This is for the next version ? About button, I wanted to select the buttons of dates before and after. Here, I can't because they are disabled.   I would like to know how to get the list of selected buttons days ?

Comment: No we made no change for this. You can override createDay() and create a button that acts differently when `setEnabled(false)` is invoked.